# How would one calculate the exact height/width of a text with html/css/jquery?

Tags: html, jquery, css, math, calculation

We ultimately want to give the clients the choice of "Max letter height", so they can pick between 5cm, 10cm, 15cm, 20cm, etc. By choosing a letter height, the visual example should adjust accordingly (although it'll have to work in scale because I wouldn't want the text to go off-screen). Once a height is selected, the client can enter their text which should automatically start calculating the width from pixels to centimeters.

In the prototype I built, I got most of it to work but the pixels to centimeters aren't exact but I have no idea what to do to make it any better. My prototype can be found here: https://codepen.io/Crownedpride/pen/d6b6973f458ecc0c60ed59b4bcfb5acd (pardon the Dutch language!)

Please let me know if I'm unclear or not, I've been trying to make this work for way too long and I'm stuck like a rock. One last thing, there's some other code within my codepen because I'm trying to turn this into a system that'll calculate a price based on the width/height of the text.

```js
    function priceCalc() {
      // var cmHeight = $('.character-height-container').toCentimeters();
      var cmLength = $('#characters').toCentimeters();
          $('#output').text('Width: ' + cmLength.width + ' CM ' +
                        'Height: ' + cmLength.height + ' CM');
      if(cmLength.width == 0){
        $('#price').text("0");
      } else if(cmLength.width < 50){
        $('#price').text("30");
      } else if(cmLength.width < 100){
        $('#price').text("45");
      } else if(cmLength.width < 150){
        $('#price').text("60");
      } else if(cmLength.width < 200){
        $('#price').text("75");
      } else if(cmLength.width < 250){
        $('#price').text("90");
      } else if(cmLength.width < 300){
        $('#price').text("105");
      } else if(cmLength.width < 350){
        $('#price').text("120");
      } else if(cmLength.width < 400){
        $('#price').text("135");
      } else if(cmLength.width < 450){
        $('#price').text("150");
      } else if(cmLength.width > 451){
        $('#price').text("165");
      }; 
    }
    
    (function($) {
        $.fn.toCentimeters = function() {
            var element = this,
                width = parseInt(element.innerWidth()),
                // width = parseInt(element.css('width')),
                height = parseInt(element.innerHeight()),
                // height = parseInt(element.css('height')),
                centimeters = {};
            centimeters.width = (width * 0.035 ); //-- scale
            centimeters.height = (height * 0.02645833333333);
            return centimeters;
        };
    }
    
    )(jQuery);
    
    $(function() {
      var price = 0;
      priceCalc();
    });
    
    $(function() {
        $('#input-test').keyup(function() {
          $('#characters').text($(this).val());
          $('#total-characters').text($(this).val().length);
          // var a = $('#breedte').text(($(this).val().length * 25));;
          // $('#price').text(($(this).val().length * 25 * 0.70));
          $inputs.each(applyStyles);
          priceCalc();
        });
    });
    
    var $target = $('#characters'),
        $inputs = $('.mystyle :input'),
        $target2 = $('#custom-text-container'),
        $inputs2 = $('.my-background-style :input'),
        applyStyles = function() {
          $target.css(this.name, this.value);
          $target2.css(this.name, this.value);
        };
    
    $inputs.on('keyup click change', function() {
        $inputs.each(applyStyles);
        $inputs2.each(applyStyles);
      priceCalc();
    });
    $inputs2.on('keyup click change', function() {
        $inputs.each(applyStyles);
        $inputs2.each(applyStyles);
        priceCalc();
    });
```

```css
    /* #breedte:after {
      content:" cm breedt";
    } */
    body {
      text-align:center;
      font-family:Arial;
    }
    #total-characters:after {
      content:" karakters"
    }
    #price:before {
      content:"€ ";
    }
    #price {
      font-size:36px;
      color:green;
      font-weight:bold;
    }
    .character-height-container {
      height:36px;
      display:block;
      margin:0px;
      padding:0px;
    /*   background-color:#ed7703; */
    }
    #characters {
      display:inline-block;
      font-size:40px;
      font-family:'arial';
      overflow:hidden;
      color:#333;
      line-height:40px;
      background-color:;
      margin:0px;
      padding:0px;
      height:;
      vertical-align:text-bottom;
    }
    #custom-text-container {
      border:2px solid #c3c3c3;
      padding:10px;
      min-height:51px;
      background-color:;
      text-align:center;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="display-characters">
      <div id="custom-text-container">
        <div class="character-height-container">
          <p id="characters"></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <p id="total-characters">0</p>
    </div>
    
    <!-- <div class="display-characters">
      <div id="custom-text-container">
        <p id="characters"></p>
      </div>
      <p id="total-characters">0</p>
    </div> -->
    <div class="display-price">
      <p id=output>Width: 0 cm Height: 0cm</p>
      <p id="breedte"></p>
      <p id="price">0</p>
    </div>
    
    <form action="">
      <label for="test">Vul hier je tekst in</label>
      <input type="text" class="text" id="input-test"><br><br>
      
      <div class="mystyle">
      <label for="font-size">Letter hoogte: </label>
      <select name="font-size" id="font-size">
        <option name="font-size" value="40px">40 px</option>
        <option name="font-size" value="60px">60 px</option>
        <option name="font-size" value="80px">80 px</option>
      </select><br><br>
      
      <label for="font-family">Kies een font: </label>
      <select name="font-family" id="font-family">
        <option name="font-family" value="arial">Arial</option>
        <option name="font-family" value="arial black">Arial Black</option>
        <option name="font-family" value="Helvetica Neue">Helvetica Neue</option>
        <option name="font-family" value="courier">Courier</option>
        <option name="font-family" value="Verdana">Verdana</option>
      </select><br><br>
        
        <label for="color">Kies een letter kleur: </label>
      <select name="color" id="color">
        <option name="color" value="Black">Black</option>
        <option name="color" value="White">White</option>
        <option name="color" value="Red">Red</option>
        <option name="color" value="#ed7703">Oranje</option>
        <option name="color" value="Green">Green</option>
        <option name="color" value="Yellow">Yellow</option>
        <option name="color" value="Blue">Blue</option>
      </select>
      </div><br>
      
      <div class="my-background-style">
      <label for="background-color">Kies een achtergrond kleur: </label>
      <select name="background-color" id="background-color">
        <option name="background-color" value="White">White</option>
        <option name="background-color" value="Black">Black</option>
        <option name="background-color" value="#f2edd3">Beige</option>
        <option name="background-color" value="#d3ecf2">Licht blauw</option>
        <option name="background-color" value="#f2d3ed">Licht roze</option>
        <option name="background-color" value="#ad3434">Donker rood</option>
      </select>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: whta is your problem? the problem is making the text ''5cm'' ''10cm'' instead of Pixels?

Comment: @AlexisGarcia not really. Currently if you enter a text, the font-size will be 40px. The height and width of the text you've entered should be calculated and shown as centimeters instead of pixels but I can't figure out how to make this consistent. Line-height seems to be the biggest pain.

Comment: Maybe my idea is possible with FabricJS? Instead of clients set up the height of letters, they can select the canvas size. As they insert their text, they can click on it to resize it, and then on the right, it could show the actual size in centimeters? No clue if that's possible but it looks interesting.